# Yii getTypeText()

Tags: php, function, yii

I am a complete newbie in the world of Yii and doing my best to learn the framework as best as I can, while reading the book on Yii - '**Web Application Development Using Yii and PHP**' by *Jeffrey Winesett*,

I came across :

Two specific public functions :

```
public function getTypeOptions(){
        return array(self::TYPE_BUG=>'Bug',self::FEATURE=>'Feature',self::TASK=>'Task');
    }
```

And :

```
public function getTypeText(){
        $typeOptions = $this->typeOptions;
        return isset($typeOptions[$this->type_id]) ? $typeOptions[$this->type_id] : "unknown type ({$this->type_id})";
    }
```

Now I understand that getTypeOptions returns the array for the dropdown list for the TypeOptions in the _form.php file, however, in the other function getTypeText(), in the variable :
**$typeOptions**, we are directly calling the function like this :

```
$typeOptions = $this->typeOptions;
```

without specifying the full function name of 
"**getTypeOptions**"

Shouldnt it have been :

```
$typeOptions = $this->getTypeOptions();
```

How is the "**get**" of **getTypeOptions();** ommitted? Can this method always be applied?

Is it Yii specific or something of PHP that I dont know about?

I am sorry if the question is a very basic one. I would be highly obliged if someone who has read the book answer me.

Comment: $this->typeOptions is referring to the public variable $typeOptions. If you look in the file, toward the top, you'll see the line 'public $typeOptions.' It's not referring to the getTypeOptions() function.

Comment: Nope, there is no public $typeOptions in my code. The only typeOption variable is the one that I have described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, whenever you have a `getAttributeName` method in your model, you can use `$this->attributeName` to return the value of the method as if it were an attribute. It's called a "virtual attribute." Here's a wiki page about it: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/

You'll see that used a lot in Yii documentation and tutorials. For example, the `Yii::app()->getClientScript()` method is often just called using `Yii::app()->clientScript`

It also comes in really handy when you're using CGridView, because you can define a method like `getAttribute()` in your model, then add a CGridView column with the name `'attribute'` to access it.

You can do this because of a PHP getter magic method in the CActiveRecord class. I'll paste that method below if you're interested:

```
/**
     * PHP getter magic method.
     * This method is overridden so that AR attributes can be accessed like properties.
     * @param string $name property name
     * @return mixed property value
     * @see getAttribute
     */
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if(isset($this->_attributes[$name]))
            return $this->_attributes[$name];
        elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->columns[$name]))
            return null;
        elseif(isset($this->_related[$name]))
            return $this->_related[$name];
        elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->relations[$name]))
            return $this->getRelated($name);
        else
            return parent::__get($name);
    }
```

This is known as a getter magic method and it's invoked when the attribute can't be found or accessed. You can use this same type of method outside of Yii as well: http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful insight!! :) I really learned a lot from it. !!

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP functionality; [Magic Methods](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/deciphering-magic-methods-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is something specific to Yii. In particular, the base class [`CComponent`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent) overrides the [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__get` and `__set` to allow this syntax:

> A property is defined by a getter method, and/or a setter method.
>   Properties can be accessed in the way like accessing normal object
>   members. Reading or writing a property will cause the invocation of
>   the corresponding getter or setter method, e.g
>
> ```
> $a=$component->text; // equivalent to $a=$component->getText();
> $component->text='abc';  // equivalent to $component->setText('abc');
> ```
>
> The signatures of getter and
>   setter methods are as follows:
>
> ```
> // getter, defines a readable property 'text'
> public function getText() { ... }
> // setter, defines a writable property 'text'
> public function setText($value) { ... }
> ```

You can browse the actual implementation online [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/base/CComponent.php#L94-L175).